# How to get a count when using group by and having

Tags: sql, t-sql

My query below is returning me 31 rows of '`1`'.  Even tho I am doing a `COUNT()` on it.

I take out the `COUNT()` and it returns me 31 rows of the status_number.  so it is returning the correct amount of results that I am expecting, but how do I force it to return 31 instead of 31 rows of '`1`'.

```
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT d.status_number)
FROM dealers d
INNER JOIN contracts c ON d.status_number= c.status_number
WHERE d.iagent_id = 79 AND d.status_code IN ('A', 'R')
AND d.status_number NOT LIKE '%demo%'
AND c.sale_date > DATEADD(MONTH, -4, GETDATE())
GROUP BY d.status_number
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.sale_date ) >= 5
```

Currently Returning:

```
(No column name)
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Need it to return:

```
(No column name)
31
```

`Table d` is a list of users, status_number is their unique identifying number within the system.  status_code is whether they are active/inactive etc.

`table c` is a list of contract sales.  I am trying to only return a count of users who have sold 5 or more contracts in the past 4 months.

The query returning 31 is the correct result.

Comment: remove `group by d.status_number`. you are counting the rows from that column.

Comment: @vkp This returns me 50.  Which is an incorrect number.  It's like it isn't taking the having clause into effect when I remove the group by.

Comment: Please post sample input data and clarify the purpose of your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you want something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT d.status_number
      FROM dealers d INNER JOIN
           contracts c
           ON d.status_number = c.status_number
      WHERE d.iagent_id = 79 AND d.status_code IN ('A', 'R') AND
            d.status_number NOT LIKE '%demo%' AND
            c.sale_date > DATEADD(MONTH, -4, GETDATE())
      GROUP BY d.status_number
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.sale_date ) >= 5 
     ) cd;
```

That is, you need two aggregations, so you need to do two aggregations, using either a subquery, CTE, or some related construct.  Your query does not need `COUNT(DISTINCT)` in the outer query because `status_number` is already distinct because of the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thank you.  I'm not sure how to mark the answer since both technically work?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT d.status_number)
FROM dealers od
where exists 
   (Select * from dealers d
       JOIN contracts c 
          ON c.status_number= d.status_number
    WHERE d.status_number = od.status_number 
       and d.iagent_id = 79 
       AND d.status_code IN ('A', 'R')
       AND d.status_number NOT LIKE '%demo%'
       AND c.sale_date > DATEADD(MONTH, -4, GETDATE())
    group by status_number 
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.sale_date ) >= 5)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thank you.  I'm not sure how to mark the answer since both technically work?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a count of how many of a status number you have after grouping by status number, so of course you're going to get a lot of 1s.

If you want a count of distinct status numbers, remove the `group by` clause from your query.

If you want a count of how many rows belong to each different status number, remove the `distinct` clause in the count.